# Is a business trip a valid reason for expedited visa request?

Tags: visas, usa, us-visa

I have a corporate meeting upcoming in a few weeks, and the standard waiting time can easily exceed a year. Is this a valid reason to request expedited processing?

Comment: Last year one of my colleagues was applying for a US visa to go to a conference, and according to him this reason was not accepted for accelerated processing. Things may have changed since then so not posting as an answer.

Comment: https://www.uscis.gov/forms/filing-guidance/how-to-make-an-expedite-request#:~:text=You%20can%20generally%20request%20expedited,have%20obtained%20a%20receipt%20notice. covers possible reasons. A corporate meeting does not seem to meet any of the reasons listed.

Comment: @JonCuster "the inability to travel for work that would result in job loss" or "losing a critical contract" look like the closest ones, but it probably would be too far a stretch to say that it threatens my job. Only hinders it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case if anyone else needs it - I used the support contact form on the visa agency website, and the answer from the "U.S. Visa Information Service (Yatri)" was "you can apply for expedited visa in such case". The results aren't guaranteed, of course.